# Call MMQGIS plugin from command line

Tags: python, qgis

I want to automatize some qgis process probably with python. I found an interesting article (http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html) which describes how can I see the processing command in the logs. I checked it, and it worked for the built-in commands, but I also need to use a plugin, called MMQGIS. The log doesn't contain the process command of this plugin. Can I call it somehow from the command line?

The other solution for me if I can create a flat-end edged buffer only with the built-in functions because then I don't need to use this plugin, and hopefully the log will contains the processing command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference to another plugin from your plugin importing plugins dict from qgis.core:

```
from qgis.core import plugins  #QGIS2
from qgis.utils import plugins #QGIS3
```

then you can list all exposed methods and attributes of the desired plugin. In your case:

```
dir (plugins['mmqgis'])
```

you'll get

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'animate_columns', 'animate_columns_action', 'animate_lines', 'animate_lines_action', 'animate_menu', 'animate_rows', 'animate_rows_action', 'attribute_export', 'attribute_export_action', 'attribute_join', 'attribute_join_action', 'buffers', 'buffers_action', 'color_ramp', 'combine_menu', 'create_menu', 'delete_duplicate_action', 'delete_duplicate_geometries', 'float_to_text', 'float_to_text_action', 'geocode_menu', 'geocode_street_layer', 'geocode_street_layer_action', 'geocode_web_service', 'geocode_web_service_action', 'geometry_convert', 'geometry_convert_action', 'geometry_export', 'geometry_export_action', 'geometry_import', 'geometry_import_action', 'grid', 'grid_action', 'gridify', 'gridify_action', 'hub_distance', 'hub_distance_action', 'hub_lines', 'hub_lines_action', 'iface', 'import_export_menu', 'initGui', 'kml_export', 'kml_export_action', 'merge', 'merge_action', 'mmqgis_add_submenu', 'mmqgis_menu', 'modify_menu', 'search', 'search_action', 'search_select_menu', 'select', 'select_action', 'sort', 'sort_action', 'spatial_join', 'spatial_join_action', 'street_address_join', 'street_address_join_action', 'text_to_float', 'text_to_float_action', 'unload', 'voronoi', 'voronoi_action']
```

now if you want to execute a plugin method:

```
plugins['mmqgis'].attribute_join()
```

then you have to study the mmqgis plugin architecture in the deep to call the methods you need with the appropriate methods and with the appropriate parameters